# SharePoint 2010 development with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: 2010, visual-studio

What is the community recommendation regarding SharePoint 2010 development with Visual Studio 2010 vs. 2012? I am allowed to install 2010 Pro on my new machine or I may choose 2012 Pro.  There may not be a right or wrong answer, but I'd love some feedback.  I feel like I will fall behind in other development efforts if I hold to 2010.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a personal choice of which one you prefer. I prefer to use Visual Studio 2012 and I haven't had any problems developing solutions for SharePoint 2010.

If you want to try out 2012 then don't let the SharePoint version hold you back.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I needed.  I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: How to get the project templates for SP 2010 in VS 2012? Am unable to see the SP 2010 empty project templates, from where will I download?

Answer (score 1):

VS 2012 will work with SP 2010 (but not with SP 2007).

Comment: Cheers mate.  Thanks for the input.  Is it preferable in your opinion to VS2010 for SP2010 development?

Comment: If you have a team that has an existing VS2010/SP2010 development process, I see no need to upgrade VS (until you update to SP2013). But if you're starting fresh with SP2010, I'd go VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of content on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=whats%20new%20in%20visual%20studio%202012%20for%20SharePoint%202010&ac=4). Also, I wrote an article with more details from the SP2010 perspective that will be published in the [Dutch Information Workers eMagazine](http://www.diwug.nl/e-magazines/Pages/default.aspx) "real soon now."